# Several blocks sharing same variable

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to share a common variable in several blocks? The following code doesn't work (context not propagated) so how can I do it other way?

```
{% with shared=my_value %}
    {% block A %}
    .. using shared variable ...
    {% endblock %}
    {% block B %}
    .. using shared variable ...
    {% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Either pass the variable from each view or write a custom context processor: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: I agree but for me this is a functionnal "feature" of Django. The `with` buildin tag should be able to change tag context.